# Jquery datatables how to set pagination property after initializing it

Tags: jquery, angular, datatable, datatables

I have a table with id teacherstable. I am using datatable for that. The code is as follows.

```
this.teacherstable = jQuery('#teacherstable').DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "No records to display.",
                },
                responsive: true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "data": this.teachers,

                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "title": "Modified Date",
                        "mData": null,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            return row["ModifiedDate"];
                        },
                        "visible": false,
                        "bSortable": true,
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Teacher Name",
                        "mData": null, "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            return row["FirstName"] + "  " + row["LastName"];

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Email",
                        "mData": null, "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            return row["Email"];
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Mobile Number",
                        "mData": null, "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            return row["PhoneNumber"];
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Date Of Birth",
                        "mData": null, "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            return row["DateofBirth"];
                        }
                    },
                                   ],

            });
```

Now my problem is that i am getting teachers data from server .Based on that recieved data i have to enable and disable pagination in datatable with attribute `pagination:false`. How to do this. Any suggestions would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operation :

```
jQuery('#teacherstable').DataTable({
    [...],
    "paging": ( "your condition" ? true : false),
    [...]});
```

Comment: actually i am using it in angular. I have 2 nav tabs as follows 1)retired Teachers 2)Present Teachers. On clicking one of these two tabs. for the first tiem the datatable is intialized. Now for past teachers i dont need pagination and for present teachers i need pagination. If i click on present teachers the datatable is initialized and when clicking on past teachers the datatable is not initialized. How to find a solution for this.

Comment: Angular is a one-page application so I guess a datatable should be initialized just once. I would suggest you to have 2 datatables so that each tab has got its own datatable with its own parameters.